# What is the return value of the “inline assembly” code？

Tags: linux, assembly

```
// gcc -g stack.c -o stack  
//  
unsigned long sp(void){ __asm__("mov %esp, %eax");}  
int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{  
    unsigned long esp = sp();  
    printf("Stack pointer (ESP : 0x%lx)\n",esp);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Please check the above code. And in fact, the sp() will return the esp register value via esp->eax, I guess. But why? The default return value of sp() is eax?
Who could tell me more about it? Thanks!

Comment: A good resource for calling conventions in different systems is http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

Comment: Also about calling conventions: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way a processor architecture organizes arguments, calls, and returns, (and [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) to kernel) i.e. [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), is specificed in the ABI (application binary interface). For Linux on x86-64 you should read the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) document. And yes, the returned value for a function returning a `long` is thru `%eax` on x86-64. (There is also the [X32 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI))

Notice that it is mostly conventional, but if the convention changes, you'll need to change the compiler, perhaps the linker, the kernel, and all the libraries. Actually, it is so important that processor makers are designing the silicon with existing ABIs in mind (e.g. importance of the `%esp` register, `SYSENTER` instruction....).

Answer (score 2):

This is the rules!

The *calling convention* used by GCC for 32-bit assembly is for the return value of a integer-returning function to be the value in `%eax`.  GCC adopts this for inline assembly functions as well.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for all the details.

Comment: Inlining is doe by GCC at the GIMPLE level, much before register allocation.

Answer (score -1):

IIRC the correct command should be "mov eax, esp" instead of "mov esp, eax".

```
unsigned long sp(void){ __asm__("mov %eax, %esp");}
```

Comment: The gcc compiler uses the "AT&T backwards notation" for assembly, meaning that all arguments are reversed compared to Intel's and Microsoft's assembly notation.

Comment: Thanks. I should get more experience then.